# Swing no valida usuarios

Tags: java, java-swing, login, intellij-idea

Espero todo bien!

Estoy realizando un programa para gestionar eventos. El problema es que lo estoy realizando con Swing en IntelliJ, y se me ha complicado un poco (no uso Netbeans porque me da un poco de problemas con mi laptop). La cosa es que he puesto el boton de "Login" pero este al darle click en el boton este nunca me lee el usuario que tengo por defecto que es el de admin o cualquier otro usuario que quiera poner, ya que siempre me da la alerta que el usuario no existe :( . Espero me puedan dar una mano con el proyecto.

No sé si tengo errores en el actionListener o en donde está el error para poder corregirlo.

Saludos y gracias de antemano!

```
package Proyecto1;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class javaTicketsLogin extends JFrame {

    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JTextField userBox;
    private JPasswordField passBox;

    //Constructor de la ventana del login.
    public javaTicketsLogin() {
        this.setTitle("Java Ticket System");
        this.setSize(600, 600);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        iniciarComponentes();

    }

    //Metodo para inicializar
    private void iniciarComponentes() {
        colocarPaneles();
        colocarBotones();
        colocarEtiquetas();
        colocarCajasTexto();
        colocarListasDespegables();

    }

    private void colocarPaneles() {
        //Panel principal
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.getContentPane().add(mainPanel); // Agregamos el panel

    }

    private void colocarBotones() {

        userBox = new JTextField();
        passBox = new JPasswordField();

        //Boton de salir
        JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        exitButton.setBounds(500, 520, 80, 30);
        exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        mainPanel.add(exitButton);

        //Boton de login (en este tengo el problema)

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        loginButton.setBounds(250, 350, 100, 25);
        mainPanel.add(loginButton);

        ActionListener userLoginButton = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String adminUser = "admin";
                String adminPass = "admin";

                if (adminUser.equals(userBox.getText())) {
                    String contrasena = "";

                    for (int i = 0; i < passBox.getPassword().length; i++) {
                        contrasena += passBox.getPassword()[i];
                    }

                    if (adminPass.equals(contrasena)) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has ingresado correctamente");
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, contraseña incorrecta");
                    }

                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario no registrado");
                }


            }
        };

        loginButton.addActionListener(userLoginButton);
    }

    private void colocarEtiquetas() {

        //Etiqueta del programa
        JLabel topLabel = new JLabel("Sistema de registro y acceso");
        topLabel.setBounds(200, 100, 200, 100);
        topLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        mainPanel.add(topLabel);


        //Etiqueta de usuario y contraseña
        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Usuario");
        userLabel.setBounds(150, 250, 100, 30);
        userLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        mainPanel.add(userLabel);

        JLabel userPass = new JLabel("Contraseña");
        userPass.setBounds(130, 300, 100, 30);
        userPass.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        mainPanel.add(userPass);

    }

    private void colocarCajasTexto() {
        //Cajas de Texto
        JTextField userBox = new JTextField();
        userBox.setBounds(200, 250, 200, 30);
        mainPanel.add(userBox);

        JTextField passBox = new JPasswordField();
        passBox.setBounds(200, 300, 200, 30);
        mainPanel.add(passBox);

    }

    private void colocarListasDespegables() {
        String[] userLevel = {"Administrador", "Usuario Normal", "Usuario Restringido"};
        JComboBox listaDespegable = new JComboBox(userLevel);
        listaDespegable.setBounds(225, 170, 150, 50);
        mainPanel.add(listaDespegable);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javaTicketsLogin mainPanel = new javaTicketsLogin();
        mainPanel.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema está en ésta parte de código:

```
 private void colocarCajasTexto() {
        //Cajas de Texto
        JTextField userBox = new JTextField();
        userBox.setBounds(200, 250, 200, 30);
        mainPanel.add(userBox);

        JTextField passBox = new JPasswordField();
        passBox.setBounds(200, 300, 200, 30);
        mainPanel.add(passBox);

    }
```

Estas creando y añadiendo ahi los campos de texto a nivel local, y no estas usando los que tienes como global.
Por esa razon, el programa te muestra login incorrecto, dado que está tomando el texto de los campos a nivel global, y pues estos no tienen nada (ni siquiera son añadidos al programa). Para que funcione tu codigo debes quitar las instancias de ese metodo, por lo que asi quedaría:

```
 private void colocarCajasTexto() {
    //Cajas de Texto

    userBox.setBounds(200, 250, 200, 30);
    mainPanel.add(userBox);


    passBox.setBounds(200, 300, 200, 30);
    mainPanel.add(passBox);

}
```

Y otra cosa, para verificar la contraseña, no es necesario iterar sobre el arreglo e ir concatenando, basta con poner:

```
String contrasena = new String(passBox.getPassword());
```

Comment: Hola Edgar! Eres grande, te agradezco por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme con esto. Ya por fin, pude hacer el login necesario para seguir con las demás funciones. Infinitas gracias!

Comment: @Juan un placer haberte ayudado! Me da mucho gusto que te haya funcionado y puedas continuar con tu programa.

Comment: @Juan bienvenido a SOe. Por favor, revisa el [tour] para ver cómo marcar una respuesta como correcta.